# `docker compose up --build` not recreating container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

When making changes to something that affects an image that a service uses, running `docker compose up --build` should rebuild that image and then recreate the corresponding service's container so that it uses the new image.

> If there are existing containers for a service, and the service’s configuration or image was changed after the container’s creation, docker-compose up picks up the changes by stopping and recreating the containers (preserving mounted volumes). To prevent Compose from picking up changes, use the --no-recreate flag.
> See https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/.

I've noticed recently that this is not the case, i.e. if I make a change to a dependency of an image, `docker compose up --build` will rebuild the image (as expected), but will not recreate the container. `docker image ls -a` shows both the old and new images, but `docker compose images` shows that the old images is still being used.

### Versions

```sh
$ docker --version
Docker version 20.10.12, build e91ed5707e
$ docker compose version
Docker Compose version 2.3.3
```

### Recreate the issue

#### Minimal files

`compose.yaml`

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  a:
    build:
      context: .
```

`Dockerfile`

```
FROM python:3.8-slim

COPY main.py ./main.py
CMD python main.py
```

`main.py`

```py
print("1")
```

#### Steps

- `docker compose up --build`
- `docker compose images`

  - note the `Image Id`
- modify `main.py`

  - change `print('1')` to `print('2')`
- `docker compose up --build`

  - a new image will be created because a dependency (`main.py`) has changed
  - however the **old** code in `main.py` executes
- `docker compose images`

  - the **old** `Image Id` is still listed
- `docker compose up --build --force-recreate`

  - the modified code in `main.py` executes
- `docker compose images`

  - the new `Image Id` is now listed

Comment: Does `docker-compose up --build` (with a single hyphenated `docker-compose` command word) work consistently?  I've seen a couple of inconsistencies in the Compose reimplementation inside the `docker` binary go by on SO, and you might need to open a Docker bug report.

Comment: `docker-compose up --build` has exactly the same behaviour. Bug (https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9308) logged against `docker/compose` project.

Comment: This behaviour has been replicated by someone else. See the bug report at https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/9308.

Comment: This problem has been fixed in docker compose 2.3.4.